# How does a middleware automatically handle exceptions throw by the middleware below it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Let's say we have the following code:

```
public class MiddleWareFirst
{
   private RequestDelegate next;

   public MiddleWareFirst(RequestDelegate nextDelegate) {
      next = nextDelegate;
   }
   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
      await context.Response.WriteAsync("Start \n");

      if (next != null) {
         await next(context);
      }
   }
}

public class MiddleWareSecond
{
   private RequestDelegate next;

   public MiddleWareSecond(RequestDelegate nextDelegate) {
      next = nextDelegate;
   }
   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
      if (next != null) {
         await next(context);    // <---- should throw the exception caused by MiddleWareThird
      }
   }
}

public class MiddleWareThird
{
   private RequestDelegate next;

   public MiddleWareThird(RequestDelegate nextDelegate) {
      next = nextDelegate;
   }
   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
      throw new System.Exception();
   }
}
```

and build the pipeline as:

```
// Configure method in startup.cs
app.UseMiddleware<MiddleWareFirst>();
app.UseMiddleware<MiddleWareSecond>();
app.UseMiddleware<MiddleWareThird>();
```

You can see `MiddleWareThird` throw an exception. When I run the application, I can see the output of the webpage is "Start", which confuses me, shouldn't it be a 500 error?

Because we know that `await` can throw the exception of a task. So for `MiddleWareSecond`, since it doesn't use try catch block to catch the exception, the task that return to `MiddleWareFirst` should contain the exception internally. Since `MiddleWareFirst` doesn't use try catch block neither, so the exception will be propagated to the web server which should generate a 500 error page. But the output is normal, so how does the exception thrown in `MiddleWareThird` magically get swallowed?

Comment: When you debugged through it did `throw new System.Exception();` ever get hit in the debugger?

Comment: @mjwills no, the exception is swallowed, that's why I'm confused, who catch the exception?

Comment: So you did hit the exception, or you didn't, when debugging? To be clear, I want you to put a breakpoint on `throw new System.Exception();` and run the code. Did you hit the breakpoint - yes or no?

Comment: @mjwills I did put a breakpoint on `throw new System.Exception();`, it did hit the breakpoint (hasn't executed the `throw new System.Exception();` at that moment though), then I step in, then no, it just run normally. so somehow the exception is swallowed

Comment: @mjwills could you also have a look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349189/how-response-headers-be-sent-to-the-client-when-the-middleware-pipeline-hasnt-f

Answer (score 1):

> exception will be propagated to the web server which should generate a 500 error page

As you have already started response with `await context.Response.WriteAsync("Start \n");` status code `200` is written to the response stream as per HTTP protocol you send status in the first line.

If an exception will be thrown before `WriteAsync` you will get `500` from the server as you expect.

This is handled by `aspnet core` infrastructure, also in logs you may notice that the exception is logged.

Of course, you can have custom middleware to handle exceptions like `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware`

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f74c6f12d868b8e5c91e85f1a2bcbd1134ed5fd5/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs#L90-L127